# the if case in this code doesnt work while there is no syntax error

Tags: c, string, strcmp, equality-operator

```
if(s.name=="kolkata")      
{
    printf("the details");
}
if(strcmp((s.name,"kolkata")==0) 
{
    printf("the details");
}
```

The first 'if' case has no syntax error still it doesn't work,while the second 'if' case does work very efficiently, why?

Comment: you haven't used strcmp in the first if case, that is why. Having no syntax error is necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: Because first if statement comparing the object to object and they are different objects. second if is comparing content of the object.

Comment: Because the second statement is not syntactically correct. And where do you have got the "information" that the second is not efficient? You never ran this code, so you never measured its performance, didn't you?

Answer (score 6):

It is not like the first case **doesn't work** at all, it just works in a way which is ***not intended***.

As per the code,

```
 if(s.name=="kolkata")
```

is an attempt to compare the pointers themselves. It does not compare the content of the memory location pointer by these pointers.

Coming to the point where you were expecting *syntax errors*, quoting `C11`, chapter 6.5.9, the constraints of the Equality operator, (`==`)

> - both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;

So,

```
if(s.name=="kolkata")
```

is a perfectly valid and legitimate C code, from syntactical point of view. Logically, when you're expecting to compare the contents of the memory area pointer by the pointers, this code is useless and makes no sense.

Comment: if the input is "kolkata" then the output have must be " the details".But it wasn't so.

Comment: What was your *actual* code? `if(strcmp((s.name,"kolkata")==0) ` does not compile.

Comment: @HemanshuSaraf if you change the code to print *different* messages, you then won't cause confusion as to which of the presently-identical messages is printed, and your apparent contradiction.